# Cannot find symbol method drawImage(SlidingBlockModel, int, int, int, int, <nulltype>)

Tags: java, drawimage

I'm trying to make a sliding block game. In this class I've used the drawImage method to display the blocks of the "puzzle", using the drawImage method of the Graphics object g2. But at the paint class method I get this error: Cannot find symbol method drawImage(SlidingBlockModel, int, int, int, int, ). Any suggestions? I appreciate your time in reading this. Thank you in advance. :)

Zoi

The code follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;

class SlidingBlockPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
int numCols;
int numRows;

SlidingBlockModel SBModel;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SlidingBlockFrame w = new SlidingBlockFrame();
    w.setVisible(true);
}


public SlidingBlockPanel(int nc, int nr)
{
    numCols = nc;
    numRows = nr;
    addMouseListener(this);
    SBModel= new SlidingBlockModel(numCols, numRows, "puzzle.jpg");
}
int getCol(int x)
{
    return x*numCols/getWidth();
}
int getRow(int y)
{
    return y*numRows/getHeight();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
{
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
{
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
{
    int thisCol = getCol(event.getX());
    System.out.println
    ("you clicked in column " + thisCol);

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
{
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
{
}


Rectangle getRect(int thisCol, int thisRow)
{
    // if input is out of range, return "null"
    if(thisCol <0 || thisRow < 0)
        return null;
    if(thisCol>=numCols || thisRow>=numRows)
        return null;

    // otherwise, make and return the Rectangle
    int w = getWidth()/numCols;
    int h = getHeight()/numRows;

    int x = thisCol*w;
    int y = thisRow*h;

    Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
    return myRect;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.black);


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    // we'll use Graphics2D for it's "drawImage" method this time

    for (int i = 0;i<numCols;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<numRows;j++)
        {

            SBModel.getSubimage(i, j);
            Rectangle r = getRect(i, j);
            g2.drawImage(SBModel,r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height,null);


        }
    } 

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's mean that your SBModel isn't java.awt.Image type.

Try to change your class SlidingBlockModel in that way:

```
SlidingBlockModel extends Image {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `SlidingBlockModel` inherit from `java.awt.Image`? It would have to, since the method you are calling has the signature `void drawImage(Image, int, int, int, int, ImageObserver)`. That seems to be the only possible problem with the code.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for your answers. I found the error. It was the object class that caused the problem after all. Your answers were valuable. Thank you for helping me to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

`SlidingBlockModel` needs to be a subclass of `java.awt.Image` in some way - either directly or indirectly. So you either need to extend from `Image`, `BufferedImage` or `VolatileImage`.

It looks like it's not at the moment which is why it's complaining that it can't find the given method type, it can't find a method with that matching signature.